# com.sun.tools.javac.code.Symbol$CompletionFailure: class file for com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap not found

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to implement GoogleMap in android & getting `Symbol$CompletionFailure`

I get this error while building the project

I was able successfully run the sample android project

**app gradle**

```
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```

**project gradle**

```
buildscript {
    apply from: 'versions.gradle'
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.3.41'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath gradlePlugin.android
        classpath gradlePlugin.googleService
        classpath gradlePlugin.butterknife
        classpath gradlePlugin.fabric
        classpath gradlePlugin.firebase
        classpath gradlePlugin.kotlin
        classpath gradlePlugin.langapi
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
            credentials { username authToken }
        }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
        maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/drummer-aidan/maven" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots" }

        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Can you post app level gradle file ?

Comment: This is app level gradle file . U want project level file ?

Comment: Yes I forget project level

Comment: posted..........

Comment: @M D : Any update on this

Comment: Strange for me. I have used Google Maps v2 in many apps but never seen this issue before. I tell you one thing issue is due to some conflicting same classes. 2 or more dependency have same classes. So you  should find this and exclude redundant classes from one of the dependency and your issue will solve

Comment: okay ... let me figure out the conflict ... Thanks :)

Comment: So have you figured it out or not? I'm also stucked in the same issue

Comment: @MuhammadMuzammil : I had modularized project ,so used `play-services-maps` gradle in module . This caused problem . Then I put `play-services-maps` gradle in `app` module and it worked

Comment: Yup that just resolved my issue too, don't know why but it works. Also i didn't put `play-services-maps` in `app` module I just changed its configuration from `implementation` to `api` in my module. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The google maps service should be added to the **app-level gradle file** if it's not already included.

```
   implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
```